# SEGV using pushback

Tags: c++

```
vector<char*> *v =new vector<char*>[size];
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    char *buf=new char[1024];
    ------
    ------
    ind=****;
    v[ind].push_back(buf); // i am sure ind is not our of bounds.
}
```

I declared an array of vector using new operator and filled it in a loop. but it encountered a SEGV. i couldnt figure out how it occured . my GDB backtrace provides me last stack function to  " .....include/c++/4.4.5/ext/new_allocator.h:105".
code snippet is described below.

Comment: Well, either you have omitted the part of the code that actually causes the segfault, or the index is actually out of bounds. By the way, using a plain array of `vector`s is almost always useless and a bad idea, use a `vector<vector>` instead.

Comment: Please provide the complete stack trace and consider using a `vector` or `vector`s instead.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having a feeling you actually want

```
auto vv = vector<vector<string>>(size/*, vector<string>(1024)*/);
```

Then work with that

```
for(auto v& : vv)
{
    v.push_back("ola");
}
```

etc.

Comment: @MatsP ninjaed that real quick! Thx anyways